# c++ initializers list std::array best performance

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, initializer-list

Given this class:

```
template<class value_type, std::size_t row_count, std::size_t column_count>
class matrix 
{
public:
    matrix()
    {
    }

    matrix(std::array<std::array<value_type, row_count> ,column_count> matrix_data)
        : data(matrix_data) {}

    void 
    insert(std::size_t row, std::size_t column, value_type value)
    {
        data[row][column] = value;
    }

    value_type 
    get(std::size_t row, std::size_t column) const
    {
        return data[row][column];
    }

private:
    // Initialised to zero
    std::array<std::array<value_type, row_count>, column_count> data{};
};
```

The data array gets initialised to zero. But if I would use the second constructor (non default one) it would overwrite it with other values.

Is there a way to improve the performance so the values only get intialised to zero when the first constructor is used?
Im guessing a for loop is less efficient than the `data{}` statement?
Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the second constructor zero initializes the array?

Comment: BTW, return by const reference to avoid copy of `value_type`. (apply similarly to the setter).

Comment: I thought the second constructor would use the copy constructor of std::array? I didnt assume the second constructor zero initializes the array.

Comment: data is initialized in the class body, so unless a constructor initializes it, that will be its default.  If you want to leave the array uninitialized and containing garbage, then remove {} after the declaration of data, and constructors that don't explicitly initialize it will leave it that way.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis So you're saying the constructor will be called *instead* of the {} if the second constructor is called?

Comment: I'm saying, the class-body initializer is used only if the constructor doesn't offer its own initialization.  Think of it as a default value that constructors can replace if they so choose, by providing their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a class member like

```
std::array<std::array<value_type, row_count>, column_count> data{};
```

what you are saying is that in all constructors that do not initialize `data` use `data{}` as the initializer.  If you have a constructor that provides a member initializer for `data` then the compiler will use that initializer instead of the default you provided.  That means in

```
matrix(std::array<std::array<value_type, row_count> ,column_count> matrix_data)
    : data(matrix_data) {}
```

that `data` will be copy initialized from `matrix_data` and there is no zero initialization step.